# Getting context using AnnotationConfigApplicationContext in Akka Actor

Tags: spring, scala, akka

how do I get annotation context . I am looking at this code ([copied from here](https://github.com/huntc/akka-spring/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/typesafe/Akkaspring.scala)) :

```
case object Tick
case object Get
@Named
class CountingService {
  def increment(count: Int) = count + 1
}
@Named
@Scope("prototype")
class Counter @Inject() (countingService: CountingService) extends Actor {

  var count = 0

  def receive = {
    case Tick => count = countingService.increment(count)
    case Get  => sender ! count
  }
}

@Configuration
class AppConfiguration {
  @Bean
  def actorSystem = ActorSystem("Akkaspring")
}

object Akkaspring extends App {
  val ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext
  ctx.scan("org.typesafe")
  ctx.refresh()

  val system = ctx.getBean(classOf[ActorSystem])

  val counter = system.actorOf(Props().withCreator(ctx.getBean(classOf[Counter])))

  counter ! Tick
  counter ! Tick
  counter ! Tick

  implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)

  // wait for the result and print it, then shut down the services
  (counter ? Get) andThen {
    case count ⇒ println("Count is " + count)
  } onComplete { _ => system.shutdown() }
}
```

**but what if I want to use the the counter in another Actor
e.g** :

```
class CounterUser extends Actor {
val countingService =  system.actorOf(Props().withCreator(ctx.getBean(classOf[Counter])))
def receive = {
    case Tick => countingService ! Tick
  }
}
```

**how do I get the context in the other actor ?**

how can I inject other `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` for testing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `CounterUser` is a Spring bean, you can do this:

```
class CounterUser @AutoWired() (ctx: ApplicationContext) extends Actor {
  val countingService =      system.actorOf(Props().withCreator(ctx.getBean(classOf[Counter])))
  def receive = {
    case Tick => countingService ! Tick
  }
}
```

Here is another way to do the same by using Akka extensions: https://github.com/bijukunjummen/akka-scala-spring/tree/upgrade-spring

Comment: Thanks, I will try that . is there a way if the CounterUser is not Spring bean ?